# I met an error when I run the JGibbLDA demo on its homepage

Tags: java, lda

The [example on the homepage](http://jgibblda.sourceforge.net/#1.1._Description_) is run on Linux, one of the commands is:

```
$ java -mx512M -cp bin:lib/args4j-2.0.6.jar jgibblda.LDA -est -alpha 0.5 -beta 0.1 -ntopics 100 -niters 1000 -savestep 100 -twords 20 -dfile models/casestudy/newdocs.dat
```

I want to run this on Windows.

> change the : after the bin to ;
>
> then run it and here is the result:

[image]

You can see the sampling process is all right but the saving process is wrong. I want to ask if this is a bug or because of something stupid I did?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and what solved it was giving LDA the folder where the input was separated from the data file.

Look closely to the last two parameters:

```
$ java -mx512M -cp bin:lib/args4j-2.0.6.jar jgibblda.LDA -est -alpha 0.5 -beta 0.1 -ntopics 100 -niters 1000 -savestep 100 -twords 20 -dir models/casestudy/ -dfile newdocs.dat
```

these are the two last parameters that matter:

```
-dir models/casestudy/ -dfile newdocs.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

use this command:

```
$ java -mx512M -cp bin:lib/args4j-2.0.6.jar jgibblda.LDA -est -alpha 0.5 -beta 0.1 -ntopics 100 -niters 1000 -savestep 100 -twords 20 -dir models/casestudy-en -dfile newdocs.dat
```

you have to determine input directory by -dir parameter.